# Convert line-broken paragraphs into single paragraphs? (Folding text?)

Tags: regex, text, textmate

I have searched everywhere for an answer to this, but I think I must not be using the right lingo... I have text like this:

```
This text is actually just
one paragraph, but every
few words are broken to a
new line, and that's
annoying as hell, because
I have to go to each line
and fix it by hand...

Then there's a second
paragraph which does the
same thing.
```

I would like to convert that to:

`This text is actually just one paragraph, but every few words are broken to a new line, and that's annoying as hell, because I have to go to each line and fix it by hand...`

Then there's a second paragraph which does the same thing.

I've tried as many regex techniques as I could think of in TextMate, and can't find any macros or commands to re-wrap the text... The text in question is a result of content editors on one of my sites pasting from Word... I think they may even type this way (holdover from typewriter days!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, there's probably something you can do with lookaheads. I tried it, but it didn't work (perhaps didn't try enough). So you can try to do this with a series of commands.

First replace any series of spaces with just a single space character:

`:%s/ \+/ /g`

Then replace all newlines with a space:

`:%s/\n/ /g`

Then replaces all double spaces with double newlines:

`:%s/  /^M^M/g`

The `^M` can be obtained in [vim](http://www.vim.org/download.php) by doing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>.

Or, you could even do:

`:%s/  /\r\r/g`

This is a little ghetto, but it should work :)

Comment: I can do that with a regex in search/replace in textmate, but if I do that, it also puts all paragraphs together in one line...

Comment: Works! I just need to wrap that up into a script or macro, and I'll be golden. Thanks :)